# Printing and Returning issues in Python

Tags: python, function

i'm having a newbie problem with python, my function does not return nothing on console.

Here's the code;

```
planets = [
    ("Mercury", 2440, 5.43, 0.395),
    ("Venus", 6052, 5.24, 0.723),
    ("Earth", 6378, 5.52, 1.000),
    ("Mars", 3396, 3.93, 1.530),
    ("Jupiter", 71492, 1.33, 5.210),
    ("Saturn", 60268, 0.69, 9.551),
    ("Uranus", 25559, 1.27, 19.213),
    ("Neptune", 24764, 1.64, 30.070)
]
name = lambda planet: planet[0]
size = lambda planet: planet[1]
density = lambda planet: planet[2]
distance = lambda planet: planet[3]

planets.sort(key=size, reverse=True)
print(planets)

def lettercase(planets):
    return all(n[0].isupper() for n in planets

lettercase(planets)
```

I only have the list organized and printed the way i asked, but not the uppercase "checker" function.

I'm trying to organize a list for a specific element and later create a function that checks if the first letter of each element is in Uppercase, if so returns True, if not returns False.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the newbish question, i'm a beginner in programming.

Comment: Can you edit your question to be more specific about what your intended output is?

Comment: You never call the `lettercase` function. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: You have to call the function.

Comment: Where is the call?

Comment: It should be `n[0][0].isupper()` to test the first character.

Comment: The question is unclear.  The title says "my function does not return nothing on console", implying that you see no output at all, but in the question you also say "I only have the list organized and printed they way i asked", implying that you _do_ see some output.  Which is it?

Comment: Use `print(lettercase(planets))` to see the output.

Comment: The code design is a bit odd, consider using a dictionary to map your labels to your data

Comment: Also consider learning how to use classes, instead of functions like `name = lambda planet: planet[0]`

Comment: `lettercase()` _returns_ something, but you're not printing the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of functions isn't printed automatically. You need to call `print()` to do it.

```
print(lettercase(planets))
```

Also, you need to call the `name` function in `lettercase`:

```
def lettercase(planets):
    return all(name(n)[0].isupper() for n in planets)
```